# EADDRINUSE :::3000 in jest

Tags: jestjs

I know this error means that port 3000 is already in use but I also tried a different port but I am still getting the same errors for some specific tests only.

This is the code of one of those test

```
  describe("GET /", () => {
    it("should return all genres", async() => {
      await Genre.collection.insertMany([
        {name: 'genre1'},
        {name: 'genre2'}
      ]);

      const res = await request(server).get('/api/genres');
      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
      expect(res.body.length).toBe(2);
      expect(res.body.some( g => g.name === 'genre1')).toBeTruthy();
      expect(res.body.some( g => g.name === 'genre2')).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

Any way to solve this error?

listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

```
  10 |
  11 | const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
> 12 | const server = app.listen(port, () => winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
     |                    ^
  13 |
  14 | module.exports = server;
  15 |

  at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
  at Object.listen (index.js:12:20)
```

● /api/returns  › Should return 400 if customerId is not given

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62801
```

This is what i'm getting in the console

Comment: Do you definitely get that error from this test? I can't see what would throw an error about a port already being in use

Comment: I'm getting this error for only 8 tests out of 27. Sometimes I don't get this error. I restart the computer but it didn't help either.

Comment: Do you have anything that's running before these tests, to spin up a server?

Comment: No, I'm not running anything else.\n Currently, I'm running 5 tests 2 unit and 3 integration there is nothing wrong with the unit tests. If I run the integration one by one they work fine. But when I try to run all of them together with some test in integration test files give an error. This does not happen if I run them separately ( by changing the name from genre.test.js to genre.  to disabled )

Comment: It seems like at least some of your tests are trying to create instances of express on a port, though it's not possible to tell why that is from the code you've provided

Comment: did you find the solution for this???

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that the issue is down to not closing the server between test runs in Jest.

If you're using `jest --watch` to run your tests then it might help to add an `afterAll` handler?

Example minimal express app:

```js
// app.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Server port
const HTTP_PORT = 3000;

// Start server
server = app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
    //console.log(`Server running on port ${HTTP_PORT}`);
});

// Root endpoint
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({"message":"Ok yah!"})
});

// Default response for any other request
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
});

module.exports = server;
```

Test file:

```js
// app.test.js
const app = require('../app');

describe('GET /', () => {
  let response;

  it('proves Jest works', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });

  it('proves maths still works', () => {
    expect(1+1).toBe(2);
  });

});

// remembering to CLOSE the server after tests completed.
afterAll(async () => {
  await app.close();
});
```